# How to tell typescript to get generic type from argument object?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

Say I have following definition:

```
interface Options<T = any, K = void> {
  scope?: K,
  success: (this: K, result: T) => any,
  failure: (this: K, result: T) => any
}

interface HttpClient {
  request<T>(opts: Options<T>)
}
```

From above definition, typescript wont give me correct type for this in `success` & `failure`. How do I tell `Typescript` that K should be `scope` property of the first argument.

Example usage:

```
class Abc {
  //...

  save() {
    var client = new HttpClient()
    client.request({
      scope: this,
      success: function(result) {
        this // here no intellisense
      }
    })
  }

  notify(event, data) {
    this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, { detail: data }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `success: (result) => { this.notify....},`?

Comment: It's about type intellisense in JavasSript, with the help of Typescript, so your solution isn't solving the problem. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `request<T>(opts: Options<T>)` you are fixing the type `K` with its default value `void`. If you want to keep that type variable as something variable it must still be a type parameter in `request<T,K>`.

This code correctly deduces the type of `this` as `this`:

```
interface Options<T = any, K = void> {
  scope?: K,
  success: (this: K, result: T) => any,
  failure?: (this: K, result: T) => any
}

class HttpClient {
  request<T, K>(opts: Options<T, K>) : any {}
}

class Abc {
  //...

  save() {
    var client = new HttpClient()
    client.request({
      scope: this,
      success: function(result) {
        this // here intellisense offers `notify` and `save` completion
      }
    })
  }

  notify(event, data) {
    this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, { detail: data }));
  }
}
```

Other minor code changes: I had to make `failure` optional and `HttpClient` a class just for the purposes of getting some code that doesn't complain about anything higher up than `notify()`.

Comment: Thats very interesting. And I just realized i cannot do much, since I'm trying to use it via many layers, just to have intellisense. The example I gave wasn't correctly demonstrating my usage. Thanks for your help though, your answer should be correct for the case.